# Meaning of "seek out like water"

Tags: phrases, metaphors

What does *seek out like water* mean in the following sentence?

> The epitaph contained a final message from Maynard, who expressed a note of deep thanks to all of her supporters, whom she "sought out like water" during her life and illness.

Comment: I see this is your 17th question, which is great because it means that you're getting answers. But you have yet to award a single user who has solved your problem or whose answer was the most helpful. Please click on the check mark, it's a small gesture of kindness and an indication to other users that your question has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

It's a metaphor.

Water is life giving, cooling, satisfying, relieves and assuages thirst.

Maynard needed assuaging, comforting, support and encouragement in her struggle to end her life with dignity. So she compared those who supported her to water, which is necessary to life and health; in this case they were assuaging her spirit.

Comment: You may be correct about the intent of the metaphor; but the metaphor itself seems weak and ambiguous.  Water also occurs as storm waves, floods, rain falling on parades, and places where people drown. “There are an estimated 372000 annual [drowning deaths worldwide](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs347/en/).”

Comment: @jwpat7 - air is necessary for life, but we don't have a negative connotation associated with it when people freeze to death. I am not critiquing the writer's skill; I'm just explaining what I believe the words are trying to convey. I doubt she intended to be negative.

Comment: It'd be helpful to include any references you can show in support.

Comment: @Kris - it's a very old idea. *As the deer pants for the water brooks, So my soul pants for You, O God.* Ps. 42:1